# Loading the aspx combobox at client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have used aspx combobox and bind the values at the client side through ajax call, the values are loaded but was not displayed in the combobox, i want to know where i did the mistake

**please find the code below:**

```
 public static List<string> GetDepartments()
            {
                ABTestNewEntities obj = new ABTestNewEntities();
                List<string> lst = new List<string>();
                lst.Add(string.Format("{0}-|-{1}", 0, "Please Select"));
                lst.Add(string.Format("{0}-|-{1}", 1, "Develop"));
                lst.Add(string.Format("{0}-|-{1}", 2, "Test"));
                lst.Add(string.Format("{0}-|-{1}", 3, "HR"));
                return lst;           
            }



    $(document).ready(function () {
                alert("inside function");

                $("#btn").click(function () {                              
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "NewOrder.aspx/GetDepartments",
                        data: "",
                        datetype: "json",
                        async: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            var response = data.d;

                            $("#ddldepartment").empty();                      

                                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                                    var item = response[i].split("-|-");
                                    var Option = "<option value='" + item[0] + "'>" + item[1] + "</option>";
                                    Option.text = item[1];
                                    Option.value = item[0];
                                    $("#ddldepartment").append(Option);

                                }
                                return false;
                            //});
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert("Error");
                            alert(data.error);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details please? For example, code sample...

Answer (score 0):

use [WebMethod]

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetDepartments()
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        lst.Add(string.Format("{0}-|-{1}", 0, "Please Select"));
        lst.Add(string.Format("{0}-|-{1}", 1, "Develop"));
        lst.Add(string.Format("{0}-|-{1}", 2, "Test"));
        lst.Add(string.Format("{0}-|-{1}", 3, "HR"));
        return lst;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AddItem() Method

here are the References about dynamic load item in the Combobox at clientside(js)

https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/js-ASPxClientComboBox.AddItem(text)

and this is the example or demo

https://codecentral.devexpress.com/e1332/